# How come I don't need to pass params to article_params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How does the `article_params` method get access to `params` without it being passed as a parameter?
Thanks in advance.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  private def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end
  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    if @article.save
      redirect_to @article
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `params` is not a variable, it's a method in `ActionController::Base` which returns the parameters passed in by the call, and, being a method, is available to be called by any method in any controller.  In fact you can reference `params` in views, so it's not only a method, it's a helper method.

As described in https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html

> All request parameters, whether they come from a query string in the
>   URL or form data submitted through a POST request are available
>   through the params method which returns a hash.

Comment: Whats funny though is that the description is incorrect. Its not a hash - its an instance of ActionController::Parameters.

Comment: @max yes, I was thinking that. The docs are an oversimplification.